# How to write spam filter

Tags: java, email-spam

I'm stuck in having to write a simple spam filter
I'm not really sure about how I'm going to do it.

So far I've come up with wordlist and domain filtering, which will give or remove points up to a certain threshold.

For example, if you're writing about "v1agr4" from a blacklisted domain, you'll get like 2 points for spam, but if you're writing about "v1agr4" from a hotmail.com account, you'll get only 1 "spam point".

Do you guys have any other suggestions / ressources?

This is more about learning spam filters than developing something enterprise grade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some really good algorithm info here:

http://www.paulgraham.com/spam.html

http://www.paulgraham.com/better.html

But, seriously, why reinvent the wheel?

Just download K9: http://keir.net/k9.html

Answer (score 3):

Some open source Java projects related to Bayesian Spam Filtering (that was mentioned by LFSR Consulting):

- [Classifier4j](http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/)
- [jBNC](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=49871)
- [Naiban](http://www.tempeststrings.com/naiban/)

And one extra for C++:

- [SpamProbe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/spamprobe/)

Answer (score 1):

Look into  [Bayesian Spam Filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering).

I know perl has a library for it, so I'd assume java would have one too.

Answer (score 0):

I've written [one with all the bells and whistles](http://code.google.com/p/sblam/).

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate that to a distributed service. [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) is a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a spam filter depends upon your demands for scalability.

If you want a scalable solution, then content-filtering is probably not the smart choice to make as it is very CPU and memory consuming, and you would instead rather choose either reputation based filtering or blacklist based filtering, which will be way more CPU friendly on your server as well as much easier to write.

I wrote a [a post on my blog](http://programmers-tips.blogspot.co.il/2016/07/how-spam-filters-actually-work.html) that explains the idea behind writing a spam filter from a programmer's point of view and covers all the options from content based filtering to black list based filtering.